# Counting arguments of an arbitrary callable with the C++ detection idiom

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, sfinae, detection-idiom

I've been using the C++ [detection idiom](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4436.pdf) create a metafunction for determining the number of arguments to an arbitrary callable.  So far, I have this (full, compilable code at http://ideone.com/BcgDhv):

```
static constexpr auto max_num_args = 127;

struct any { template <typename T> operator T() { } };

template <typename F, typename... Args>
using callable_archetype = decltype( declval<F>()(declval<Args>()...) );
template <typename F, typename... Args>
using is_callable_with_args = is_detected<callable_archetype, F, Args...>;

template <typename F, size_t I = 0,  typename... Args>
struct count_args
  : conditional<is_callable_with_args<F, Args...>::value,
      integral_constant<size_t, I>,
      count_args<F, I+1, Args..., any>
    >::type::type
{ };

template <typename F, typename... Args>
struct count_args<F, max_num_args, Args...> : integral_constant<size_t, max_num_args> { };
```

This works great when none of the callable arguments are lvalue references:

```
void foo(int i, int j) { }
static_assert(count_args<decltype(foo)>::value == 2, "");
```

But when any of the arguments are lvalue references, this fails (for obvious reasons, since the callable archetype has a substitution failure):

```
void bar(char i, bool j, double& k);
static_assert(count_args<decltype(bar)>::value == 3, "doesn't work");
```

Does anyone know how to generalize this idea to make it work with lvalue references as well?

Comment: This is pretty brittle. (And it doesn't handle arbitrary Callables, either).

Comment: @T.C. What arbitrary callables did you have in mind that it doesn't handle?

Comment: Pointers to members.

Comment: @T.C. True, but that generalization is not hard to make and just complicates the question.  All that is needed is additional archetypes for all forms of INVOKE() in the specification of Callable and a big or statement.

Comment: Not quite. You can't do the full INVOKE logic with expression SFINAE alone (or at least, not easily). (A cheat is to use SFINAE-friendly `result_of`.)

Comment: @T.C. Isn't that essentially what the standard library does in the `functional` header?  (e.g., circa line 269 of https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/3cb1e7bf3c9673970832d3dec625a08512c6f530/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/functional)

Comment: It uses a tag to constrain it, instead of expression SFINAE. Look at the hoops its `result_of` jumps through to get the right tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
struct any { template <typename T> operator T() { } };
```

to:

```
struct any {
  template <typename T> operator T&&() { }
  template <typename T> operator T&() { }
};
```

[live example](https://ideone.com/VDt4dt)

We have both an lvalue and rvalue implicit casting operator.  So, we ... good?

Answer (score 3):

The following works (for small `max_num_args`):

```
struct any    { template <typename T> operator T(); };
struct anyref { template <typename T> operator T&(); };

template <typename F, typename... Args>
using callable_archetype = decltype(std::declval<F>()(std::declval<Args>()...) );
template <typename F, typename... Args>
using is_callable_with_args = std::is_detected<callable_archetype, F, Args...>;

template <typename F, size_t I = 0,  typename... Args>
struct count_args
  : std::conditional<is_callable_with_args<F, Args...>::value,
      std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I>,
      std::integral_constant<std::size_t,
                             std::min(count_args<F, I+1, Args..., any>::value,
                                      count_args<F, I+1, Args..., anyref>::value)>
    >::type::type
{};

template <typename F, typename... Args>
struct count_args<F, max_num_args, Args...> :
    std::integral_constant<std::size_t, max_num_args> {};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cb7861b6c3ae410a)

But code has to be optimized, as the complexity is `2**max_num_args` :/

Answer (score 0):

Building off of the answer from @Jarod42, a slightly better definition of `any` seems to do the trick in the vast majority of cases (excluding cases that cause `callable_archetype` to be a substitution error for other reasons; for instance, classes with deleted copy constructors, the invocation of which wouldn't be valid anyway):

```
struct any {
  template <typename T,
    typename = enable_if_t<
      not is_same<T, remove_reference_t<T>>::value
    >
  >
  operator T();

  template <typename T,
    typename = enable_if_t<
      is_same<T, remove_reference_t<T>>::value
    >
  >
  operator T&();

  template <typename T,
    typename = enable_if_t<
      is_same<T, remove_reference_t<T>>::value
    >
  >
  operator T&&();
};
```

This seems to work in all of the same cases as the previous answer without the exponential scaling.

[Demo](http://ideone.com/r2PRvL)

Comment: So, why the fancy SFINAE?

Comment: @Yakk because... I'm not as smart as you.  But in all seriousness, going this direction allows me to add a metafunction predicate to `any`, which was going to be the next step anyway.  (Yes, this could be done in the other case too).  But yes, I like your answer better.